# using functions to display numbers in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers and I have to use a function to display them in celsius,  they are in fahrenheit now.

```
nums = [30,34,40,36,36,28,29,32,34,44,36,35,28,33,29,40,36,24,26,30,30,32,34,32,28,36,24,32]
def fahrenToCel(c):
    c = (f - 32) * (5 / 9)
    return c
print fahrenToCel(nums)
```

this is what I have, can someone please help me

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: Please do your homework alone. This is the fifth question in a row and you just copy/page the code you get from each answer to the next question.

Comment: Learning how to program by asking random questions is a tedious and slow process. You might wish to [start with a tutorial first](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) -- written by someone who has put thought into how to introduce programming concepts one at a time, with plenty of examples, and problems for you to solve -- will doubtless give much better results than just flailing around asking for help here. We're happy to help, but [the Pasteur Institute's Guide](http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/) looks like a more useful way to spend an evening.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list `the_list` and you want to apply a function `f` to each element, creating a new list of the results:

```
new_list = [f(x) for x in the_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems to take as input a single number, yet you're giving it a list of numbers. If you want to generate a list of converted numbers using that function, you can use list comprehension:

```
cels = [fahrenToCel(fah) for fah in nums]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ','.join([str(fahrenToCel(fahren)) for fahren in nums])
```

This will not only create a new list, but will also join it as a comma-separated string.

If `nums` is rather long, you can save some memory and performance by using a generator expression instead of list comprehension. You just have to take off the square brackets:

```
print ','.join(str(fahrenToCel(fahren)) for fahren in nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use a *for* loop to iterate over the list and printing each result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# def farentoCel(x): ...
# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    for each_num in sys.argv[1:]:
        print farentoCel(int(each_num))
```

As others have said you can replace this explicit loop with a list comprehension (expression), or even a generator comprehension (in newer versions of Python).

In this case I'm showing a very simple skeleton for you to use for testing simple functions.  The **if _ *name* _ == '_ *main* _':** suite is a Python convention used to separate your function, class, and other definitions from the run-time of your code.  This can be used to structure your code so that it can be re-used in (imported into) other code while also exposing some functionality in a command line utility (wrapper) or providing a default interface (perhaps a GUI).

In the fairly common case where your module doesn't have simply accessible utility (where it's only useful when incorporated into other code) then you can use the '_ *main* _' suite to contain unit test cases.