# displaying celsius in python- functions

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using functions to display numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642263/using-functions-to-display-numbers-in-a-list)

```
x = [30,34,40,36,36,28,29,32,34,44,36,35,28,33,
     29,40,36,24,26,30,30,32,34,32,28,36,24,32]

def fahrenToCel(x):
    return (x - 32) * (5 / 9)


print fahrenToCel(x)
```

I know I have asked a couple of times, but I am still having issues.  I just need to use a function to have that list of numbers displayed in celsius.  This is the very last part I have to do, but I cannot figure it out.  Please help

Comment: Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.  Also, feel free to try more things than simply typing a single line of code and asking questions here.  You can try a few combinations of lines of code.  You're allowed to experiment.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = [30,34,40,36,36,28,29,32,34,44,36,35,28,33,
     29,40,36,24,26,30,30,32,34,32,28,36,24,32]

def fahrenToCel(x):
    return (x - 32) * (5.0 / 9) # 5.0 to make result float (you can explicitly convert to float as well)


print [fahrenToCel(item) for item in x]
```

Comment: You can also use `from __future__ import division` to get `int / int = float` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `x` is a numpy array, python will not know how to iterate over the values in `x`. You need to either loop over the values in x and pass each element to `fahrenToCel()` and place the returned value in a new list, or have `fahrenToCel()` take a list and do the loop internally and return a new list.

You might want to look at the following chapter of the python tutorial:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html

Or search for other examples of how to iterate through lists.

**Update** For example:

```
def stupidfunc(y):
    return y 

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [stupidfunc(x) for x in a]
```

or

```
def stupidfunc2(y):
    return [stupidfunc2(x) for x in y]

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = stupidfunc2(a)
```

Comment: can you give me an example please, i do not exactly understand what you are saying

Answer (score 2):

What about you'd use `map(fahrenToCel, x)` ?

```
x = [30,34,40,36,36,28,29,32,34,44,36,35,28,33, 29,40,36,24,26,30,30,32,34,32,28,36,24,32]

def fahrenToCel(f_temp):
    return (f_temp - 32) * (5.0/9)

celsius_list = map(fahrenToCel, x)
```

By the way, make sure you write `5.0/9` in your `fahrenToCel` function since `5/9 == 0`

---

Read about [map function in python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)